# Can not sign up using social sign in

Tags: django, facebook, oauth-2.0, authomatic

I'm getting an error when I try to use social sign-up/sign-in on Facebook. I'm using Authomatic and my site uses the django framework. I have previously been successful in doing this with Facebook on websites I've worked on. the only difference I can pick up is that now I'm using version 2.9 of Graph API.

Here is error message:

> **URL Blocked**: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not 
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and 
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth 
>   Redirect URIs.

Comment: And your research into this error message - that gets asked about frequently - has turned up nothing …?

Comment: Nothing I have not tried...